# How to make a loop do something during a certain time frame in JS

Tags: javascript, function, time

I'm pretty new to JavaScript so please keep that in mind when answering my question.

I'm trying to make something where it asks the user questions during a certain time frame. Questions are asked using the `window.prompt()` method. I have a `do while` loop going on in a function called `askquestions()` as you can see:

```
var randomNo1;
var randomNo2;
var time;

do {
  randomNo1 = Math.random() * 9;
  randomNo1 = Math.round(randomNo1);
  randomNo2 = Math.random() * 9;
  randomNo2 = Math.round(randomNo2);
  window.prompt("What is " + randomNo1 + " + " + randomNo2 + "?")
} while (time == 0);
```

How can I make it that `time = 1` after 30 seconds? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `time` is `undefined` in your code.

Comment: Use [the `Date` object and its methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to get the current time, add 30 seconds to it, and then in the `while` condition test that against the current time again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 using

```
date = new Date();
mil = date.getTime();
```

You do that at the beginning of your code for comparison, then get a more current one in the loop.  If the time between the two is greater than some number of milliseconds, you can exit the loop (`while(curDate.getTime()-mil<30000)` would be 30 seconds)

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out tomorrow.

Comment: user3829943's response is better than mine.  Javascript doesn't like it when while loops run for too long.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
document.setTimeout("str js code/func name call",millisec);
document.setTimeout("time=1;",30000);
```

to execute some js code once with delay

And for your specification the following method may be needed for other timing purposes:

```
document.setInterval("js code /func name call",millisec);
```

to execute at an interval

Besides,it is strongly not recommended to have a "waiting while" in your js code to provide some timing service, which may cause browser to take this thread as a not-responding thread